# Is it possible to use "*" in "--add-exports" JVM option?

Tags: java, jvm

**NB! I know I can open access to that particular package, however my goal is to open access to all internal JDK APIs**
I want to open the access to internal JDK APIs for my project, which I am migrating to JRE 17. I do not know which 3rd party libraries use which internal jdk apis so to be safe I want to open the access to all internal packages like that:

```
--add-exports java.*/sun.*=ALL-UNNAMED --add-exports java.*/com.sun.*=ALL-UNNAMED
```

I started the VM with that option, no complaints were printed but the test that was failing continued to fail with

```
cannot access class sun.security.provider.certpath.OCSP (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export sun.security.provider.certpath to unnamed module @0x23f682d2
```

**TLDR: It is not possible**

Comment: What's preventing you from running it and seeing for yourself?

Comment: I ran it and the test failed, that's why I am asking if I have not added correctly the option or it is just impossible. Are you aware of that @Michael?

Comment: If you tried and it didn't work, then obviously you can't. Using `--add-exports` and `--add-opens` should only be used in exceptional circumstances. Likely this also informed a design where wildcards are not supported. If you find the need to add it a lot (or for a lot of packages), then you''re probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any way to do this.  I sympathize with your problem, but honestly, the difficult solution is probably the better solution:  find out what each library is trying to access and grant that permission explicitly.  If possible, upgrade to versions of libraries which are themselves Java modules.

Comment: You can expect those 3rd party libraries to crash anyway, as internal APIs have changed or been removed. And you can expect more changes and more removals in the future.